# Show $\frac{x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{n}}\underset{{n\to +\infty}}{\sim} \frac{1}{x^{2n-1}}$ for every $x>1$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, taylor-expansion, alternative-proof

> Show 
>   $$\dfrac{x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{n}}\underset{{n\to +\infty}}{\sim} \dfrac{1}{x^{2n-1}}\quad \mbox{ with } x>1$$

My proof:

$$\dfrac{x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{n}}\underset{{n\to +\infty}}{\sim} \dfrac{1}{x^{2n-1}} \iff \lim_{n\to +\infty}\dfrac{x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{n}}\times x^{2n-1}=1$$

indeed,

For all  $x\in \mathbb{R}^*$

- Note that  : $$ q^{n}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\to +\infty}\quad \rm{ when}\quad  q>1 $$

then :
$x^{2n}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\to +\infty}$ and $\left(1+x^2\right)^{n}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\to +\infty}$   since  $1+x^{2}> 1$

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\dfrac{x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{n}}\times x^{2n-1}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\dfrac{x^{2n}}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{n}}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\dfrac{x^{2n}}{\left(x\right)^{2n}}=1$$

Is my proof correct ? and could we use taylor expansion ?

Reference of my question:

[image]

https://books.google.com/books?id=Ihh2uOXnRQcC&hl=fr&pg=PA97&#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Are you assuming that $|x|>1?

Comment: i just add only $x>1$ not $|x|>1$ is there difference

Comment: If $x>1$, then $|x|>1$.

Comment: @Educ I think there is a typo, it is rather $x \to +\infty$. isn't it? Please can you clarify? Otherwise my answer below is not correct.

Comment: please wait i'll add the reference

Comment: Ok, I've deleted my answer. Thanks.

Comment: so the answer provide by book is wrong ?

Comment: yes, it has to be $\lim_x$ instead $\lim_n$

Answer (score 3):

After some trouble (!) I think we can conclude that the statement is not true. Take for example $x=2$: you would have
$$
2\cdot 5^{-n}\sim \frac{1}{2}\cdot 4^{-n}.
$$
That's not true.