# Prove that $f_n(x): x\in\mathbb{R}\mapsto \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^{n}}$ converges pointwise to null function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, taylor-expansion, alternative-proof

Show that sequence of function :

$$f_n(x): x\in\mathbb{R}\longmapsto \dfrac{x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{n}}$$

converges pointwise to null function

since we found from the following link that :

> [Show $\frac{x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{n}}\underset{{n\to +\infty}}{\sim} \frac{1}{x^{2n-1}}$ for every $x>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897063/show-dfracx-left1x2-rightn-undersetn-to-infty-sim-dfrac1)

is false 
[image]

https://books.google.com/books?id=Ihh2uOXnRQcC&hl=fr&pg=PA97&#v=onepage&q&f=false

- since the proof provided by the book Is there alternative proof

Comment: To prove the pointwise convergence to the null function you have to distinguish the two cases $x=0$ and $x\ne0$ and this what'is done in the given answer.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @user296113 this is not completely true. Just look at $x=1$. The rhs term is then constant.

Comment: No for $x=1$ the sequence $f_n(1)=2^{-n}$ converges to $0$. And this is true for all $x$.

Comment: @user296113 I'm reffering to the _right hand side_ of the asymptotic relation. $1^{-(2n-1)}$ _is_ constant. So the _relation_ is not correct for that value and does not help. It also does not help for $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course $f_n(0)=0$ for any $n$ and there is nothing to prove. Suppose $x\neq 0$. Then $1+x^2=:q>1$ and 
$$
\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{1}{q^n}=0,
$$
therefore
$$
\lim_{n\to +\infty}f_n(x)=x\cdot \lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{1}{q^n}=x\cdot 0=0,
$$

Comment: so no need to use the mistake equivalence that they used in solution

Comment: Exactly: that suposed 'equvalence' would be a much stronger statement

Answer (score 0):

Let us fix $x\in \Bbb R^*$. We see that
$$f(x)=x\left(\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\right)^n$$

Since $\left|\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\right|<1$, we see that $\dfrac{f(x)}{x}$ is a geometric sequence converging to 0.